# ksoftirq ran out of sysctl and tcp accept queue drops on my netdata alarms

Tags: sockets, tcp, netstat

I often have two criticals errors :

- ip.tcp_accept_queue   1m tcp accept queue drops
- number of times, during the last 10min, ksoftirq ran out of sysctl net.core.netdev_budget or net.core.netdev_budget_usecs

On my netdata alarms.

I've tunned my sysctl like this :

```
fs.file-max = 2097152 
net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 60000
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1 
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 10240
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=htcp 
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1 
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2 
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535 
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15 
net.core.somaxconn = 65536
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536 
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824 
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144 
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144  
net.core.rmem_default = 25165824 
net.core.rmem_max = 25165824 
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 20480 12582912 25165824 
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384 
net.core.wmem_default = 25165824 
net.core.wmem_max = 25165824 
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 20480 12582912 25165824 
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384 
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000 
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.core.netdev_budget = 80000
```

(sysctl.conf behind /etc/ and ufw directories)

Only thing I can't configure is net.core.netdev_budget_usecs because of debian 9 ? And it's maybe the problem.

For example :

```
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_budget_usecs=8000

sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/core/netdev_budget_usecs: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

- softnet graph show average of 6k events/s
- sockets graph show average of 2k sockets in use

Any idea ?

What kind of information are missing ?

Thanks a lot for your lights,

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem @NakMuay? It seems that I have a similar problem with Netdata.